# c3p0: Session-Level Advisory Locks

Tags: postgresql, c3p0

I'm using c3p0 and postgres. I have a multi-threaded application where, without proper locking, different threads may accidentally update the same record. In order to prevent this, I intend to use advisory locks.

```
SELECT pg_advisory_lock(id) FROM ...;
```

However, I'm not sure whether I can actually use advisory locks in conjunction with connection pooling, since what if the connection that was used to create the locks gets closed (this is transparent to the application logic)? Do the corresponding locks get released?

Comment: I don't have a substantive comment on "advisory locks"; I've never used them. However, if you decide that they are appropriate for your application, per Craig Ringer below, it sounds as though you need to ensure they are discarded prior to a Connection being returned to the pool. The correct way to do this in c3p0 would be to create a ConnectionCustomizer (extend AbstractConnectionCustomizer) and override onCheckIn(...) to execute the `DISCARD ALL` statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, locks (advisory and otherwise) get released when a connection is closed.

They may *not* necessarily be released if the connection is returned to a pool, though; transaction-level locks will be since the pooler will `ROLLBACK` any open transaction, but advisory locks would only get released if your connection pooler knew to [run the PostgreSQL-specific `DISCARD ALL;` statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-discard.html#ALL) after returning a session to the connection pool.

> In order to prevent this, I intend to use advisory locks.

Why? You're preventing updates to a *record*, so you have an ordinary row you can lock just fine. Your process should be:

1. Check a connection out of the connection pool
2. `SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE id = 123 FOR UPDATE`
3. do the work required in the app
4. `UPDATE the_table SET whatever = blah WHERE id = 123`
5. Return the connection to the connection pool

This requires that you hold an *open transaction* on the *same connection* for the three steps. If your  architecture prevents you from doing that and returns connections to the pool after (2) then it probably prevents use of advisory locking too, since you need to *hold same underlying connection* to manage advisory locking.

If that is the case, you must use [*optimistic concurrency control*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control) (often called "optimistic locking"), a design that was created for stateless web-applications. You store a version field in the entities, and your flow is something like:

1. `SELECT col1, col2, entity_version FROM the_table WHERE id = 123` (pretend that `entity_version` comes back with the value `42`)
2. Do the work required in the app
3. `UPDATE the_table SET whatever = blah, entity_version = 43 WHERE id = 123 AND entity_version = 42`

If `entity_version` has been changed by another session the `WHERE` clause on the `UPDATE` won't match, and the update will affect zero rows. You test the rows affected count and retry the whole operation or report an error to the user, as appropriate, when this occurs.

Optimistic concurrency control is implemented by many ORMs, like Hibernate and the other JPA ORMs, already. You don't have to use it with an ORM, that's just the most common use because ORMs encourage the "select then update" anti-pattern that's otherwise something to be avoided with SQL DBs.

Comment: Optimistic locking would of course require the application to store the entity version for each locked entity. In my case, I'll probably stick to explicitly set a lock bit on the respective items, since the application logic processes entities in batches that must be processed atomically.

Comment: @dsd Why can't you just use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, the simple and standard way to do this?

Comment: The lock must hold across sessions/connections…

Comment: @dsd Sure, but can't you *retain a session* for the duration of the work? If you can't hang onto a connection you can't use advisory locking either.

Comment: Sorry, my statements might be confusing. But yes, from your answer I conclude that I cannot use advisory locks either. Part of the reason why I can't hang onto a connection is because different threads are updating the records. But it should not happen that the user schedules another process that affects records that are affected by a running process.